# Styling Html.ValidationMessageFor with Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to style my `@HTML.ValidationMessageFor` element with Bootstrap 3 but no CSS is applied. When consulting [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation), it states:

*To use, add .has-warning, .has-error, or .has-success to the parent element. Any .control-label, .form-control, and .help-block within that element will receive the validation styles.*

Even after nesting the desired `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` as stated above, no styling is applied:

[image: ValidationMessageForError]

Please see my code snippets below:

**Model Property:**

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Client ID cannot be larger than 2147483647.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Client ID must be a positive number.")]
public int searchClientID { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="client-ID">Client ID</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchClientID, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="has-error">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.searchClientID, null, new { @class = "has-error" })
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT WITH ANSWER:**

```
<div class="has-error">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.searchClientName, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
</div>
```

Comment: has-error class should be for form-group element

Comment: @PavanTeja I've tried replacing the div's class from *form-group* to *has-error* and it didn't change the styling at all. I tried applying the `has-error` class to both the div and the razor markup but it had no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dont replace `form-group` with `has-error`.I have used something similar to this recently and try the following markup.

```
            <div class="form-group has-error">
                <div >
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "help-block" })


            </div>
```

Comment: I left the `has-error` class for the `div` element and added the `help-block` class to the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` HTML helper. This worked perfectly! Thank you very much.